# How to make FILTER formula ignore blank cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am trying to build a database of all the technology resources we have in our company. I would like to have a search table on another tab where a user can narrow down what they are looking for using a few drop down menus. For example, they could choose "Laptop" from  the "Equipment" drop down, and the list would populate with all the Laptops in the company. They could then select "Las Vegas" from the "Office" drop down, and it would populate with all the laptops in the Vegas office.

I have been using the FILTER formula with various forms of logic. When I use AND, it's considering the blank cells from the unused drop downs, so it returns #N/A since it can't find any rows matching the selections plus a lot of blank cells. When I use OR, I end up getting nearly everything from the database.

I've tried using both AND and OR together, incorporating IF statements with <>"", as well as various variations incorporating all three of them, but nothing has worked. I'm at a bit of a loss. Is there any way to get FILTER to ignore the cells that are blank?

Link to a sample spreadsheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H1TQFw02ztMHe6mbvla-evMtyrCLDuHU_b2G654e_RM/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in Search!E3:

`=FILTER(Inventory!B4:I1000,if($C$3<>"",(Inventory!B4:B1000=$C$3),Inventory!B4:B1000<>$C$3)*if($C$4<>"",(Inventory!C4:C1000=$C$4),Inventory!B4:B1000<>$C$4)*if($C$5<>"",(Inventory!D4:D1000=$C$5),Inventory!B4:B1000<>$C$5)*if($C$6<>"",(Inventory!E4:E1000=$C$6),Inventory!B4:B1000<>$C$6)*if($C$7<>"",(Inventory!F4:F1000=$C$7),Inventory!B4:B1000<>$C$7)*if($C$8<>"",(Inventory!G4:G1000=$C$8),Inventory!B4:B1000<>$C$8)*if($C$9<>"",(Inventory!H4:H1000=$C$9),Inventory!B4:B1000<>$C$9)*if($C$10<>"",(Inventory!I4:I1000=$C$10),Inventory!B4:B1000<>$C$10))`

Comment: This solution is what I was going for, I just wasn't sure of the exact syntax to make it work. This works great, but I was wanting the table to be blank if nothing was selected, however with this formula if the Criteria cells are all blank, then the entire inventory is displayed. I tried playing around with some IF statements to make it blank if no criteria are selected, but it didn't really work out. I'll probably play around with it some more, but will have to use QUERY for now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: UPDATE: Just in case anyone came here with a similar problem looking for answers. The QUERY formula broke, so I revisited this one. I was able to get the list to disappear when nothing was selected by putting in an IF(AND condition. I'll paste the entire formula below.

Comment: =IFERROR(IF(AND(C3="",C4="",C5="",C6="",C7="",C8="",C9="",C10="",C11="",C12="",C13=""),"Please select from the options on the left",FILTER(Inventory!$B$4:N1012,IF($C$3<>"",(Inventory!$B$4:B1012=$C$3),Inventory!$B$4:B1012<>$C$3)*IF($C$4<>"",(Inventory!$C$4:C1012=$C$4),Inventory!$B$4:B1012<>$C$4)*IF($C$5<>"",(Inventory!$D$4:D1012=$C$5),Inventory!$B$4:B1012<>$C$5)*IF($C$6<>"",(Inventory!$E$4:E1012=$C$6),Inventory!$B$4:B1012<>$C$6)*IF($C$7<>"",(Inventory!$F$4:F1012=$C$7),Inventory!$B$4:B1012<>$C$7)*IF($C$8<>"",(Inventory!$I$4:I1012=$C$8),
 
[continued below]

Comment: Inventory!$B$4:B1012<>$C$8)*IF($C$9<>"",(Inventory!$J$4:J1012=$C$9),Inventory!$B$4:B1012<>$C$9)*IF($C$10<>"",(Inventory!$K$4:K1012=$C$10),Inventory!$B$4:B1012<>$C$10)*IF($C$11<>"",(Inventory!$L$4:L1012=$C$11),Inventory!$B$4:B1012<>$C$11)*IF($C$12<>"",(Inventory!$H$4:H1012=$C$12),Inventory!$B$4:B1012<>$C$12)*IF($C$13<>"",(Inventory!$M$4:M1012=$C$13),Inventory!$B$4:B1012<>$C$13))),"No Matches")

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Inventory!B4:I}, "where "&TEXTJOIN(" and ", 1, 
 IF(C3:C10="",,"Col"&ROW(B3:B10)-2&" contains '"&C3:C10&"'"))))
```

[image]

Comment: This works great! I typically try to avoid using QUERY, just because it can be a little temperamental, but I think this one will work perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: UPDATE: Just in case anyone came here with a similar problem looking for answers. I resorted the main inventory list and made a few formatting changes, and it broke the formula. Like I mentioned, I typically avoid using QUERY for this reason. It's just so temperamental, just the smallest change (even if it's just to formatting) can break it.  But I was able to make the other version work the way I want it to, see other update comment.

Comment: @TGordon21 share your newly broken sheet and I can fix the query for you